# Drupal 7 rewrite is removing get parameters from query string

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, url-rewriting

I've recently upgraded a site to the latest release of Drupal 7.  The site has a view that retrieves a url with query string parameters from the database and then uses the Drupal rewrite functionality to add a class to the link like so: 
    `<a class="purple-button pull-right" href="[field_database_link-url]" target="_blank">View</a>`

The issue is, since the upgrade the rewrite now removes the query string parameters.  If I modify the view to display a simple link the parameters are there and it works fine.  However, the rewrite applies styling to present a button rather than a simple link.  I can't find any settings to resolve the issue so I suspect the upgrade overwrote a modification to the Drupal core made by the original developer of the site.  Any idea how I can address this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was a bug in the latest release that in /modules/contrib/link/link.module that was causing the query strings to be stripped from the url in the token. I replaced the code in this file with the code from the pre-upgrade version and it began behaving as expected again. This, of course, is not a resolution to the issue, but at least the source of the problem has been identified. For more info: https://www.drupal.org/node/2367069

I later found that there is a patch for this issue in the dev version (7.x-1.x-dev) of this module available here: https://www.drupal.org/project/link.  Download this module and replace it in your install and you should be all set.